# How I should get the data in the Repository from an API

Tags: java, android, rx-java, mvp

I have a call to the api who emits a `Single` and I want to get access from the `Repository` for later observe it in the `Interactor`

Here is my call:

```
@GET("reviews")
@NonNull Single<Response<AppIgnoredResponseBody>> professionalsReview(
        @Header(HEADER_API_KEY) String apiKey
);
```

And my repository call who returns me a `Single` of an object `List`:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Single<List<Review>> getReviews() {
    return appCredentialsSource
            .getAppCredentials()
            .firstOrError()
            .flatMap(flo -> appNetworkSource.professionalsReview(flo.getApiKey());
}
```

Obviously my Repository didn't work. How I should made it?

Answer (score 0):

Your Review repository always returns you List then you create an empty object of Single and set reviews and return it.

Comment: And how I should do it? I know I have to return the `Single<List<Review>>` from the repository but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You don't use a service layer?

Comment: Service Layer? I only want to know what I have to write in my `getReviews()`

Comment: If you are using Spring autowire the repository and call it from controller .